# How to read only a block of text from a notepad file in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program in which you enter the roll number of the employee and it displays the required data (which is in a notepad file)
For example the notepad file contains the salary structure of 2 employees :

Name : Suprit Behera

Post : Head Of Java Development

Roll Number : 30214

---

Basic Salary Rs.41,625.00

House Rent Allowance : Rs.9,990.00

Dearly Allowance : Rs.4,995.00

Travel Allowance : Rs.8,325.00

Medical Allowance : Rs.12,487.50

---

Gross Salary : Rs.77,422.50

Cost to The Company : Rs.929,070.00

---

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Name : Sanjib Behera

Post : CEO

Roll Number : 13462

---

Basic Salary Rs.71,325.00

House Rent Allowance : Rs.17,118.00

Dearly Allowance : Rs.8,559.00

Travel Allowance : Rs.14,265.00

Medical Allowance : Rs.21,397.50

---

Gross Salary : Rs.132,664.50

Cost to The Company : Rs.1,591,974.00

---

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

So in my program , when one enters the roll number of the employee (for eg. 13462) it will display the details of that employee (i.e. from Name to Cost to the Company) (in this case the details of the employee "Sanjib Behera".
I'm relatively new to programming but I know basic ideas of OOP and inputting data to and from a notepad file.

Comment: Why don't you switch to a database? It would be much simpler to manage the things.

Comment: Well I just wanted to experiment with these things ....

Comment: As I have told i dont have much programming experience....

Comment: Do some research, and find out how to use a database.  There are plenty of tutorials out there.  Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So in my program , when one enters the roll number of the employee (for eg. 13462) it will display the details of that employee

Google it. You will find multiple java example to read files. As for design you can do following -

Create `Employee` class with instance variables that you have salary, name , roll no etc. Next read your file, parse it and save it in a `HashMap` with key as the roll number. Time complexity being `O(1)` it would give you better performance for retrieving data. Sure you can go with a database but since you have data in file you already have persistent storage so why not just build in memory cache and use it. But sure for production code database is the way to go not simple files.

Comment: Thanks man i will check out databases.....